# VMware server 1.0.7 modules incompatible with kernel 2.6.26 -- patched, where to submit?

Tags: linux, vmware, kernel, debian

- VMware server 1.0.7 installed with vmware-package
- Debian GNU/Linux testing (lenny)
- Kernel 2.6.26-1-686

There were several compile problems when trying to build the binary kernel modules from the vmware-server-kernel-source package made by vmware-package from the VMware server tarball. Recently VMware has updated their kernel module sources so as to make them compatible with kernel 2.6.25, but they broke again with 2.6.26.

```
vmmon-only/linux/driver.c:146: error: unknown field 'nopage' specified in initializer
vmmon-only/linux/driver.c:147: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type
vmmon-only/linux/driver.c:150: error: unknown field 'nopage' specified in initializer
vmmon-only/linux/driver.c:151: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type
```

That's only the first error, but there are other compile problems (in vmnet-only).

Many advice on forums are to use vmware-any-any instead, but that has its own problems (see [my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109877/unknown-ioctl-2062-2065-2066-from-vmmon-when-starting-a-vm-vmware-server-107-fo)).

As you can see from my own answer below, I've solved the problem by fixing the incompatiblities, and came up with a [patch](http://pastebin.com/f200c4eb0). Now I'd like VMware to include it in future releases, to save me and others trouble of applying it by hand after every VMware or kernel upgrade. Question: where/how do I submit such fixes to VMware?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a support request to VMware, and they assured me that my patch will reach the VMware server team.

Answer (score 2):

I've bludgeoned the kernel module into working with the 2.6.26 kernel. Here is [my patch](http://pastebin.com/f200c4eb0).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try searching the [VMware support website](http://www.vmware.com/support/)? This has been [asked in the VMware forums](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/search.do?cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&externalId=150-150690xml4).

Comment: Really, I overlooked that. Posted my solution there as well.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps http://open-vm-tools.sourceforge.net/contribute.php ?

Comment: This is for contributions to the VM tools, not to the server itself.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for this great effort..

I've used it to get VMWare Server 1.08 running on OpenFiler. The vmware-any-any patch was also suggested but I couldn't start a guest VM because of the 'not enough physical memory' error.

Now my vm's are running happily again :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot Alexey!
This sorted stuff out for myself and a colleague of mine.

Had the same issue as Bruce with the any-any patch.

One thing, I noticed that the patch was missing the @@'s at the beginning.. I've done a new pastebin that has them in it (curse their highlighting thing!)

It's here: http://pastebin.com/f2ea13d45

Thanks,
Chris